# c# .net Windows 8 App TcpClient code port to StreamSocket

Tags: c#, windows, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5, stream-socket-client

I had this code prior to .net 4.5

```
_Connection = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
_Stream = _Connection.GetStream();
```

For Windows 8 App I changed to:

```
_Connection = new StreamSocket();
await _Connection.ConnectAsync(new HostName(hostname), port.ToString());
_DataReader = _Connection.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();
_DataWriter = _Connection.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite();
```

I thought this to be the simplest solution as I don't have to change any underlying code anywhere else, as I am still using `Stream` to read/write data.

This code does not work as expected though, I manage to write stuff successfully on the stream, but when it's time to read the stream, I keep getting `'\n'` - which is far off from my expected response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution to this. Hope someone finds it useful.

All i needed to do was flush the stream in `_DataWriter` (this needs to be done everytime something is written to the stream) and then the `_DataReader` stream started working as expected.

Comment: Could you please provide an example for how you read data with your _DataReader. As far as I understand there is no obvious way to read data with it without knowing the expected data length.